# I want to Add my Automation framework created using selenium into JMeter

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter

I want add my automation framework in JMeter to perform load and performance testing. I have created Jar file of the project but I don't know how to proceed further to perform load testing. Please assist me with this or any other suggestions.

Comment: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTgwFadtPDc" i went through this video on frame work but to add framework of any stable web application how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create the load test from your Selenium test suite is just **recording** it via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Configure JMeter for recording.

   - From main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create`
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. [Configure Selenium tests to use JMeter as a proxy](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)
3. Run your Selenium tests (you can observe recorded requests under Test Plan -> [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller))
4. Perform correlation if required
5. [Add virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)

There is an alternative solution which will allow you to avoid step 4, check out [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) for details.

Comment: Thanks for providing suggestion but where should I write code from this link to my framework also "Configure Selenium tests to use JMeter as a proxy"

Comment: In your Selenium tests

Comment: I have created different packages in frame work in which i have written my code so where can i place that proxy code.